# Constructing well-defined epimorphism onto $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\Lambda$ denote the group with presentation $\langle a,b \mid
>  abab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$. Construct an epimorphism from $\Lambda$
>   onto $S_3$, making sure to check that the function is well-defined.

So I want to find a surjective homomorphism from $\Lambda$ onto $S_3$. We define $\theta: \Lambda(a,b) \rightarrow S_3$ using $a \mapsto (12)$ and $b \mapsto (23)$. Is this right? How can I check that this empimorphism is well-defined?

Comment: this presentation correspond to the **braid group** $B_2$ which is isomorphic with $\Bbb Z$

Comment: @janmarqz It is the braid group $B_3$.

Comment: mmmh... yes, sorry for my running dysgraphia

Answer (score 3):

You need to check that
$$
(12)(23)(12)(23)^{-1}(12)^{-1}(23)^{-1}
$$
is the identity permutation, which it is. So the assignment defines a homomorphism $\Lambda\to S_3$. It is surjective because the subgroup generated by $(12)$ and $(23)$ is $S_3$.

Basically, the assignment $a\mapsto(12)$ and $b\mapsto(23)$ defines a unique homomorphism from the free group $F$ on the two generators $a$ and $b$; the relation
$$
(12)(23)(12)(23)^{-1}(12)^{-1}(23)^{-1}=\mathit{id}
$$
tells you that this homomorphism factors through the quotient modulo the normal subgroup $H$ of $F$ generated by $abab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}$ and, by definition, $\Lambda=F/H$.

Comment: So you're saying that the epimorphism I gave is really from $F_2 \rightarrow S_3$ but is still correct because we nonetheless have $(12)(23)(12)(23)^{-1}(12)^{-1}(23)^{-1}=e$?

Comment: @user3772119 Not really; we first build a homomorphism $F_2\to S_3$ and notice that it factors through $H$. So the assignment indeed defines a homomorphism $\Lambda\to S_3$.

Comment: I'm sorry -- is the epimorphism I gave incorrect or just in need of further explanation, as you have provided?

Comment: @egreg: a question related: Is it possible to epimorph $\Bbb Z\to S_3$?

Comment: @user3772119 The idea is right, but you do need an explanation. There cannot be an epimorphism from an abelian group to a non abelian one.